# Github.: Trying to delete master branch gives error "! [remote rejected] master (branch master is being renamed)"

Tags: git, github

I renamed the master branch to develop and in github I can see the develop branch. When I tried to delete the master from UI I cant see the master in branches list. I tried using CLI and keep getting `! [remote rejected]     master (branch master is being renamed)` error.

Comment: While that's an odd error (it occurs nowhere in the Git source), it sounds like the name `master` doesn't show up anywhere. So if it's not *in* the repository, you can't delete it *from* the repository either. You said *I can see ... `develop` ... [but] can't see ... `master`* so it's apparently already gone.

Comment: It should be gone in repo.. but its not.. I can not rename anyother branch to master

Comment: `git push` can never *rename* a branch in the first place. There is no "rename" operation here: there is only "create" (you run `git push` with a name the other side has not yet seen), "update" (you push with a name the other side already has), and "delete".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. Github had to cancel the operation from backend of renaming a branch.. then I was able to delete master and rename another branch as master from Github UI. the issue is similar as one faced by Cpython community -> https://github.community/t/python-cpython-zombie-master-branch/206066